# Incrementing time shows #VALUE! error in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, spreadsheet, excel-2007

I am trying to increment time by 15 minutes. When I use the formula on a cell having (DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS) 01-01-2022 01:00:00, it shows #VALUE! error. The calculation steps show the following[image]

How to overcome this issue, I tried to change the cell formats but in vain.

Comment: Have you tried adding a fraction of a day?

Comment: fairly sure that's not a time it's a string that looks like a time.  in my evaluate a time reference goes straight to its underlying number for evaluation (after being a cell reference).  you can check this by trying to format the original time to a number and seeing what happens (if it stays the same its a string)

Comment: Agree with @InjuredCoding's deduction. So the question is how did the data get into the cell(s)? I tried entering such a string, and I was able to fix it by doing Data | Text to Coluimns, and splitting on the space - Excel then recognised the two elements as a date and a time and converted them to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it like this:
[image]

representing the 15 minutes (0.25 of an hour) as a fraction of 24 hours ie a day.